# Sea-Ice thickness categories

Tags: sea-ice

In the Sea-Ice models they use the Sea-Ice thickness categories. An example is the SIS model of BCC CSM (http://forecast.bcccsm.ncc-cma.net/web/?ChannelID=37, https://www.gfdl.noaa.gov/sea-ice-simulator/). Is it meant by 5 Sea-Ice thickness categories that there are only 5 discretized thicknesses the Sea-Ice can take, or are the categories separators for treating the Sea-Ice differently in each category? (if so, why would they treat Sea-Ice in each category differently?)

Thank you